# xmpp server is giving some int response on user creation how can i get that display in android application

Tags: java, android, xmpp

i am creating a android application which can create and login felicity for the xmpp server. but my question is the server setup such a way on creation of new user it will return a int value i need to display that in android application. could you please help me how to get that int value. how to capture the server response..?? thank you in advance

I have already tried some of the links but not very useful

**xmpp server is giving some int response on user creation how can i get that display in android application**

Answer (score 0):

First create a API to register a user.

Upon registration the server should send you a JSON response code as :

```
{

"id" : "1"
"error": false,
}
```

To read the response in your application you can use AsyncTask, Volley, Ion.
Here is example to use ION.

Following code will send a registration request to your server and will receive JSON response as above.

```
if (AppUtilities.isInternetConnected(this)) {
        final Builders.Any.B builder = Ion.with(this).load("your.registration.url.com");
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.setLogging(TAG, Log.VERBOSE);
        }
        builder.setHeader(ApiConstants.HEADER_KEY_ACCEPT, ApiConstants.HEADER_ACCEPT_VALUE)
                .setBodyParameter("username", username)
                .setBodyParameter("password", password)
                .as(RegistrationResponse.class)
                .setCallback(mRegistrationCallback);
    } else {
// Do something..
    }
```

Create a RegistrationResponse.class

```
public class RegistrationResponse {

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("error")
private boolean error;

public boolean isError() {
    return error;
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
   }
 }
```

After creating of the model class of Registration response that you are going to recieve create a Callback like this.

```
 private FutureCallback<RegistrationResponse> mRegistrationCallback= new FutureCallback<RegistrationResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception exception, RegistrationResponse serverResponse) {
        if (null == exception) {


         int idFromServer = serverResponse.getID();

       //idFromServer contains the integer value you were looking for.

      //To get the boolean value you can do this.

     boolean responseError = serverResponse.isError();

      }
   }
};
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: If this answer helped you in anyway to meet your requirement then you can accept my answer. I'm glad it helped you.